# Does SSRS report server keep copies of reports sent as subscriptions?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I've got SSRS reports that have email subscriptions. So report will run every month and send a copy to certain email address. User says they have deleted the message with report by mistake. Is there a way of getting that exact report that went to them last month? Is there a copy saved somewhere in report server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No. SSRS does not keep a copy. but if the data is static for that period, you could rerun with same parameters to get the same report